# Select the one table before my link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select the `<table>` before the table where the link I clicked. I can't use IDs, because I don't want to edit my jQuery every time I add a new table.

but this looks kinda bloated for me:

```
$(this).closest("table").prevAll("table").first().css( "background", "yellow" );
```

take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/syddmxfn/13/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no silver bullet for what you're trying to do.
To find the previous table,
it's necessary to go up the DOM tree until the first `table`,
and then from there find the previous `table`.

`.closest("table")` is optimal and necessary.

On the other hand, it's true that `.prevAll("table").first()` is a bit awkward.
Something like `.closestPrevious("table")` would be the best.
I searched around and couldn't find such.
So you're stuck with `.prevAll("table").first()`.

In short, bloated it may be, I think it's the best possible way.